# Footer for a page with a variable length main section

Tags: html, css

The content of the main article on my site changes dynamically with AJAX. I want to add a footer to the site but because I can't set a static height the footer always appears at the same position as the article (as if the article didn't take up any space at all in the DOM).

I guess the easiest way is to show visually what happens: [my site here](http://theexpatcoach.com/b)

If you look at the footer when the page loads you'll notice it's stuck behing the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this line for #mainSection .mainArticle:

```
position: absolute;
```

Absolute positioning takes your article out of the flow, deleting this line will make its positioning static, and this will make those elements on top of each other as intended.